# Content-Security-Policy : directive 'form-action' contains the keyword 'none'

Tags: html, content-security-policy

I encounter this error message when I enter my webpage even though it does not cause any error but I still want to get rid of it.

I am not clear about why it occurs because I do not have the word 'none' in my form-action.

Anyone know how to solve it?Thanks

> The Content-Security-Policy directive 'form-action' contains the keyword 'none' alongside with other source expressions.
> The keyword 'none' must be the only source expression in the directive value, otherwise it is ignored.

These are my headers and I do not have any header sent by PHP, what header should I modify to avoid this error?

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
<link rel="icon" href="data:;base64,=">
<meta name="google" content="notranslate"/>
```

Comment: CAN we check headers sent by php?

Comment: Content security policy can be set in a response header or a meta tag. So check in those places. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP

Comment: If you're _sure_ PHP isn't setting the header (e.g. via the `header()` command) and there isn't a meta tag being set, then you'd need to check if the webserver, or any proxy server or anything like that, is inserting the header into the response before it reaches the browser.

Comment: You haven't said what sort of server you are on, so it limits what help people can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code, framework, web server or a proxy is setting a Content-Security-Policy in a response header (or code possibly in a meta tag). It sets the directive "form-action 'none'  []". This doesn't make any sense as 'none' should be the only source listed, it should be removed once you add other source expressions. You need to identify what sets the CSP and remove 'none'.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is to see what your headers are.  There are many sites that will do this.  I recommend [cspvalidator](https://cspvalidator.org/).

Then you can try and track down where they are coming from.